# Edit SQL queries

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database with a single query in it. I can currently copy the query via VBA, using `DoCmd.CopyObject`. However, I need to be able to edit the SQL in each instance of the query individually. All the examples I have seen, however, involve recordset, which is something I am not using.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit thin on what kind of query you want to edit, but say it is a select query that doesn't need any dynamic parameters.

Then, using the `CopyObject` method, make a copy of the query as you did.  Use the `Catalog` object (you will need to reference the ADO Ext). Then, you can just change the SQL of the copy as below.  Depending on your query, it may be a View or a Procedure, but a Select query should be listed as a View.

```
Dim catDB As ADOX.Catalog
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim sQueryName As String
Dim sSQL As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set catDB = New ADOX.Catalog

catDB.ActiveConnection = cn
DoCmd.CopyObject , "Query1_c", acQuery, "Query1"
sQueryName = "Query1_c"
sSQL = "SELECT a,b,c FROM Table1"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd = catDB.Views(sQueryName).Command
cmd.CommandText = sSQL
Set catDB.Views(sQueryName).Command = cmd

Set catDB = Nothing
cn.Close
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and my apologies for the omitted detail. I have just managed to resolve it via coming across this link:

http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/211550-query-vba

Comment: @Gaioshin, I found the link you provided here of great use. It lead me to information I needed, which got me started on finding the rest of the information I needed in order to use a modal dialog to close an existing query, make some refinements, and then reopen it. Fantastic.

Answer (score 4):

I do this kind of thing all the time!  I've used VBA to rewrite Access queries as well as queries that "pass through" to a MySQL database.  Rewriting a query in VBA depends on how complicated you want to get.

I've always used `DAO`, <del>which is older technology</del> (see comments below for clarification on DAO vs ADO), but it's worked for me in this instance.  You'll need to add a reference to DAO in VBA by going to Tools > References, and then add "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library."

You might write a procedure that looks like this:

```
Sub RewriteQuerySQL(strQueryName As String, strParameter As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(strQueryName)

    qdf.SQL = "SELECT [Table].Field1, [Table].Field2 " & vbCrLf & _
              "FROM [Table] " & vbCrLf & _
              "WHERE ([Table].Field1 = " & chr(34) & strParameter & chr(34) & ");"
End Sub
```

The above code is going to change the SQL for the query you specify with the query SQL in the VBA code with the `strParameter` embedded in the SQL query.

Here's another way of doing it.  This is code I used in a sales reporting application to rewrite a query based on a salesperson's number:

```
Sub rewriteAccountsBySalesRepSortSQL(lngSalesRep As Long)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim strReplacePart As String
    Dim strSQLReplace As String
    Dim lngLocSalesperson As Long
    Dim lngLocMyRoundUp As Long
    Dim lngLocParen As Long
    Dim lngLocEndParen As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryS Accounts by Sales Rep Sorted by Diff DESC")
    strSQL = qdf.SQL

    lngLocSalesperson = InStr(strSQL, "Salesperson1)=")
    lngLocEndParen = InStr(lngLocSalesperson + 14, strSQL, ")")
    strOriginal = Mid(strSQL, lngLocSalesperson, lngLocEndParen - lngLocSalesperson)
    'lngLocParen = InStrRev(strSQL, "(", lngLocSalesperson)

    strReplacePart = "Salesperson1)=" & lngSalesRep

    strSQLReplace = Replace(strSQL, strOriginal, strReplacePart)
    qdf.SQL = strSQLReplace
End Sub
```

Instead of writing out the whole query, the code simply finds the current sales rep number and replaces it with the new number.  I actually prefer the latter method.  The latter method was used to send a query directly to MySQL, so the syntax with an Access query may be slightly different.

Comment: DAO is not "older technology" except in the sense that it was created longer ago that ADO. ADO is dead, replaced by ADO.NET, which is not usable in Access (and has very little in common with ADO other than the name and a few basic structures that are common to every data abstraction interface). DAO, on the other hand, is in full development since A2007 when the Access team got their own private version of the Jet database engine, now called ACE. DAO will continue to be updated and enhanced in tandem with enhancements to ACE, so it's the current and preferred interface of choice.

Comment: @David thanks for the clarification! The reason I mentioned that DAO was "older" was because, if I recall correctly, the Access 2002 Developer's Handbook or the VBA Developer's Handbook, 2nd edition, treat ADO as if it's the new kid on the block and DAO as if it's going out of style.  I think they even but DAO in an appendix and tried to use ADO throughout the book.  Thanks for clearing things up; now I don't feel so bad using DAO all the time :-).

Comment: Classic ADO is now dead, and has been for over half a decade. The ADO-everywhere campaign by Microsoft in the A2000/2002 time frame was a huge mistake, and was recognized by such by most experienced Access developers (who never switched to ADO for interaction with Jet data). It's sad that so much documentation at MS and elsewhere still embeds those erroneous assumptions about the future of DAO/ADO. MS really should have known better in the first place.

Comment: BTW, with current versions of Access (2003 and 2007), you likely won't need to add a DAO reference, as those are there by default in databases created with those versions. Databases created in earlier versions may or may not have the reference. I consider DAO one of the three REQUIRED references in any Access application (the other two being VBA and Access). I don't add any other references, in fact, and use late binding with any other outside library except in the most unusual cases.

Answer (score 2):

I would dissent from all the answers given here, even though they do address the question asked. I dissent because I think the question is based on incorrect assumptions -- there is no need to rewrite the SQL at all.

The question seems to assume that queries in Access have to be saved. They don't. You can execute any arbitrary SQL string at any time, either in code, or (for non-DML SQL) as the recordsource of a form or report. The SQL strings can be built on the fly and assigned as needed at runtime -- the only advantage of a saved QueryDef is if you need to use it in multiple locations.

A saved QueryDef is basically the same as a VIEW in server databases.

If the QueryDef has parameters, it's equivalent to a simple STORED PROCEDURE (i.e., ones that lack code, like IF/THEN or CASE SELECT branching).

If you would implement the SQL as a VIEW  on a server database, save it as a QueryDef in Access. If you'd do it as an SPROC in your server database, implement it as a saved parameter query.

But first of all, determine if it needs to be saved at all.

For what it's worth, I've been programming professionally in Access since 1996 and I generally don't save a lot of queries, and particularly don't save *criteria* in queries. Criteria are specific to runtime context and should be supplied at runtime, rather than saved in the QueryDef. I use saved QueryDefs for complex SQL that I need to re-use or for defining "views" (particularly those with complex joins) that are used in more than one place in the app.

The original question does not identify the context in which changing the criteria is needed, so it's really impossible to suggest the best approach. This is a case where I would fault the question for foreclosing proper discussion as it proposes a specific SOLUTION and asks how to implement it, instead of describing the PROBLEM and asking for the range of workable solutions. In order to do the latter, we'd need to know about the context (is the SQL DML or a SELECT? is it being used in code or as the recordsource for a form or report? etc.), but that's completely lacking here, so a full range of solutions is never going to be offered.